# if-statement incorrect output

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
echo ""

declare -i value=00
unset optics_status

optics_status=$(curl -I xx.xx.xx.xx:4512 | grep 'X-Trace' | awk '{print $NF}' | rev |cut -c 1-3 | rev)


if [ $optics_status != $value ]; then
    echo "result is different means I am in if loop"
    echo "stats is $optics_status"
else
    echo "result is equal means I am in else loop"
    echo "stats is $optics_status"
fi
```

`xx.xx.xx.xx` is a server IP and if I run the `curl` command separately this is the output I get.

```
user@machine-lap:~/Documents$ curl -I xx.xx.xx.xx:4512 | grep 'X-Trace' | awk '{print $NF}' | rev |cut -c 1-3 | rev
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0  8359    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
00
user@machine-lap:~/Documents$
```

As you see I've set `value` to `00` and the output of `optics_status` is also `00`. So according to the if loop, it should echo `i am in else loop` but it just echos the `i am in if loop` and I can't understand why.

To put it in simpler words, its echoing the `if` statement instead of `else`.

Comment: An integer variable in `bash` does not retain zero padding.  The string `"$value"` would be `"0"`.

Comment: And be aware that if you use `bash` arithmetic on non-zero numbers with a leading zero digit it will treat them as octal. Generally it's better to apply padding at the last possible moment - in the output statement, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `value` variable to be `00`, don't declare it as an integer in `bash`.  Declaring it as an integer with `declare -i` will prompt the shell to evaluate it as an integer, and the integer value of `00` is zero.

Observe, the following code will output `not same`:

```
declare -i value='00'
optics_status='00'

if [ "$optics_status" = "$value" ]; then
   echo 'same'
else
   echo 'not same'
fi
```

Changing `declare -i value='00'` to `value='00'` will make it output `same`.

Also note the quoting of the variable expansions above.

---

You could of course also consider promoting both variables' values to integers by comparing them using either

```
if [ "$optics_status" -ne "$value" ]; then
```

or

```
if (( optics_status != value )); then
```

but that assumes that you know that `$optics_value` is *always* going to be a string that may be converted to an integer (and a *decimal* integer rather than an octal integer too).

Comment: @Vlastimil I look at questions that interest me. We don't _really_ do pure code reviews here though. I believe there's a separate SE site for that at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (I'm not on it, maybe I should be)

Answer (score 1):

`cut`'s ranges are inclusive, so you've pulled three characters out. One of those characters might be invisible, such as a space, tab or newline. That makes the string different from the value `00`.

In general, try `set -o xtrace` to see what happens when running your script. And [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!

Comment: even if i remove the curl command completely and just set "optics_status=00", it still echos the if statement and not else.

Comment: thanks for your input l0b0. As @Kusalananda suggested above, the issue was that I declared "value" as an integer and bash would consider it a "0" instead of "00".